# How to deal with a lot of imports in the index.js file (Node)

Tags: node.js, node-modules

first post yay. I am self-taught, spend the last months working through TOP and Angelas Bootcamp and basically jumped into the cold water to build my own application. Locally everything works but when I deploy it dumps because of what I assume is very inefficient code (too many imports, too much memory needed) => Application breaks.
So my question how can I improve that I need to many imports in the index.js, it takes ages to load.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
import ejs from 'ejs';
import path from "path";

import { averageAwards, shareAwards, totalAwards, topAwards } from "./analysis/award_analysis.js";
import { averageProjects, totalProjects, allProjects, shareProjects  } from "./analysis/project_analysis.js";
import { averageOrgs, totalOrgs, topOrgs, shareOrgs  } from "./analysis/org_analysis.js";
import { averageCertificates, totalCertificates, topCertificates, shareCertificates  } from "./analysis/certification_analysis.js";
import { shareBachelor, shareMaster, sharePhd, topSchools } from "./analysis/education_analysis.js";
import { averageLanguages, totalLanguages, shareLanguages, topLanguages } from "./analysis/language_analysis.js";
import { averagePatents, totalPatents, allPatents, sharePatents } from "./analysis/patent_analysis.js";
import { averagePublications, sharePublications, totalPublications, allPublications } from "./analysis/publications_analysis.js";
import { averageSkills, shareSkills, totalSkills, allSkills } from "./analysis/skill_analysis.js";
import { averageVolunteers, shareVolunteers, totalVolunteers, topVolunteers } from "./analysis/volunteer_analysis.js";
import { averageGMAT, count_GMAT, averageTOEFL, count_TOEFL } from "./analysis/testScores_analysis.js";
import { sortedMonths, sortedYears } from "./analysis/newHirings_analysis.js";
import { sortedCompanies, averageInternships, totalInternships, shareInternships } from "./analysis/position_internship_analysis.js";
import { totalRolesCount, allRoles, bainTotal, mckinseyTotal, bcgTotal } from "./analysis/positiontitles_analysis.js";
```

So far I was able to identify:
a) Caching
b) dynamic loading of modules
However I wanted to make sure there is not a third option I missed